# Should I protect my op-amp inputs to avoid results that would "exceed the rails"?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Suppose a rail-to-rail op-amp is multiplying its input signal by 3. If its V+ is 3.3V and its V- is 0V and an input of 2V is provided, that should produce a result of 6V. Naturally, this cannot happen as the op-amp V+ is 3.3V.

Could this input damage the op-amp? What if it wasn't rail-to-rail?

If the answer to any of the above is no, let's assume that the op-amp's input can never exceed its V+. Does it still make sense to protect the op-amp inputs by clamping its maximum value? If so, would a biased diode in series with a resistor be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this input damage the op-amp?

No. The datasheet for the op-amp you are considering will have a section called "absolute maximum ratings". This section will include a rating for the maximum voltage allowable on the input pins. For a rail to rail op-amp, this voltage will necessarily be equal to or greater than the positive rail voltage. Since your input pins are less than that, your op-amp will not be damaged by the voltage applied to your input pins.

> What if it wasn't rail-to-rail?

Not all op-amps are the same. Some op-amps may have limited ability to tolerate sufficiently large differential input voltages, even when both individual inputs are within the safe range. "Low noise" op-amps are specifically mentioned in this regard. So check your datasheet.

> let's assume that the op-amp's input can never exceed its V+. Does it still make sense to protect the op-amp inputs by clamping its maximum value?

If it is 100% impossible for the input pin voltages to go outside of the range of trail voltages, then protecting the inputs is not needed. HOWEVER, you need to ask yourself whether this constraint really applies ALWAYS. Does it apply during handling if there is a static discharge? Does it apply if power is removed from the op-amp, but some power is still available to previous stages? Etc. Don't just consider normal operation, consider transient conditions.

> If so, would a biased diode in series with a resistor be the right way to achieve this?

Clamping diodes between the inputs and the supply rails is the standard way to protect the inputs. Many common ICs already have such diodes, although the amount of current they can handle is often quite limited. I would not add a resistor in series with the diode. Although that might provide some protection *for the diode*, it reduces the protection *for the op-amp itself*. Current through the diode might be reduced, but the voltage at the input might be increased. Protection can never be absolute, and I don't think a diode plus resistor gives one more peace of mind than a diode by itself, unless you *know* that there are certain transient conditions you need protection from, and you know that the extra resistor improves protection rather than degrades it.

Comment: Your caution in the second paragraph is well founded. There are some opamps (low noise IIRC) that have a bare diff pair at the input pins and can't tolerate more than a few volts between the inputs, even if both pins together can range across the full supply voltage. Their parts number escape me at the moment.

Comment: Many opamps with BJT inputs have back-to-back diodes across their inputs.  Because of those, if you put one input at 2V and the other at 3.3V/3, they won't be happy about it even though both inputs are between the supply rails.  Oops, @Neil_UK .  Actually many.  Finding a low-noise BJT one that _doesn't_ have those is not easy.  MC33078 is one without.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose a rail-to-rail op-amp is multiplying its input signal by 3. If its V+ is 3.3V and its V- is 0V and an input of 2V is provided, that should produce a result of 6V.

The opamp will clip, which is harmless. However, there are a few gotchas.

First, read the maximum ratings.

Some opamps dislike having too much voltage between their inputs. This is especially the case with precision low noise opamps: several volts between the inputs may reverse bias the input transistors too hard and cause them to break down, which may degrade noise or offset permanently. This can happen when the opamp clips, it is not necessary for the input voltage to exceed the supply rails. The usual protection against this is a pair of antiparallel diodes between the inputs. Sometimes they're included in the opamp. If they are necessary, they will be mentioned somewhere in the datasheet.

If input voltage exceeds the allowed range mentioned in the "electrical characteristics" of the opamp, then the input stage may misbehave in a variety of ways or stop working. This can manifest as output phase reversal or other problems.

If input voltage exceeds the allowed range mentioned in the "maximum ratings" then damage can occur. I'm not mentioning supply rails because some opamps will still work with the input a little bit above the positive supply, or a little bit below the negative supply, which is very convenient. Anyway, usually opamps have ESD protection diodes between inputs and V+/V- so, if the input voltage exceeds the supply voltage by more than one diode drop, current will flow into the inputs, through the diodes, and into the supplies.

In all the above cases, current can flow into the inputs, and the maximum allowed current is mentioned in the datasheet. If you expect this to happen, then even if the opamp is wired with positive gain and would not normally need a resistor on the + input, it still needs a resistor to limit input current. This increases noise, so high performance opamps sometimes implement more "creative" overvoltage protection based on current limiting.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs that would cause the output of the opamp to 'hit the rails' are not dangerous of themselves. The output will reach the maximum it can drive to, and stop, without damage. Bear in mind that with the colossal open-loop gain of most opamps, that's any more than a fraction of a mV between the inputs!

Inputs taken beyond the rails are harmful to the opamp if excessive current is allowed to flow through the protection diodes on chip. Generally a series resistor will be able to limit input current and avoid chip damage if you expect your inputs to exceed the rails. You rarely need an external clamp, unless you want to handle extreme out-of-range inputs.

Inputs taken beyond the common mode input range can cause some opamps to misbehave, generally the older types, and reverse the sign of their gain, with unexpected results.

These points apply to 'most' opamps. There are some that are more fragile, some that are more robust. Generally the more robust ones will advertise the fact prominently, and the fragile ones will say so somewhere. Always read the data sheet carefully.

Comment: "... and the fragile ones will say so somewhere ..."  but you have to dig for it.  If an op-amp _really_ can't stand too high a common-mode voltage it _should_ say so in the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section of the data sheet, but it may be in a footnote to the "common mode voltage range" specification.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data sheet!
Some very special op-amps do not have input protection.  There are no diodes from input to the supply.  It is because the diodes add noise, leakage current, capacitance or something else.  (not common but read the data sheet)
Most op-amps have very small diodes from inputs to supplies, but don't push amps through the diodes they cannot take it.
Just to prove my point I opened up 3 data sheets and two did not say anything about input protection.  (bad words removed lol) The third data sheet has a 2mA max through the input diodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your opamp has no idea about your external circuitry.  If you say "it is multiplying the input by 3" and the power rails have 0V and 3.3V and the input is at 2V, its output will swing to 3.3V (assuming full rail-to-rail) and stick there.  The negative input will consequently stick at 1.1V (namely 1/3 of the output voltage).

Many opamps have internal back-to-back protection diodes across their inputs that will clamp the differential voltage to 0.7V.  Consequently, those would engage.  They are limited in the current they can support, however, so putting them between low-impedance versions of 2V and 1.1V would be bad news, generally.

That means that your "divide-by-three" network must have an output impedance that will reduce the maximum possible current to the amount that the input diodes will tolerate.  Though you can also put part of the resistance in series with your other input (which tends to be better for non-harmonic distortion).  If audible thermal noise is a problem, you can bypass a resistor there with a capacitor.

The application notes of a datasheet will usually give you a good idea about your options and will also tell you whether or not internal input protection diodes are involved and what you may need to do about them when the opamp cannot deadpoint on every input.